# jquery .animate div disappearing

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

I'm trying to implement a jQuery .animate call to toggle the height of several div's.  One of the div's I would like to disappear as it currently does, but the other div I would like to remain visible.  How can I accomplish this?  Here's what I have so far:

```
<div 
    ...  
    onClick="$('#divDetails').animate({height:'toggle'},'slow');
    $('#divContents').animate({marginTop:'toggle',display:'block'},'slow');">
    ...
</div>
```

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use `jQuery` please bind events the `jQuery-way`. Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').on('click', function() {
        $('#divDetails').toggle('slow');
        $('#divContents').animate({marginTop:'toggle',display:'block'},'slow');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Phil, but aside from changing where the onClick event is defined, this doesn't resolve the problem.